# Dynamically select cells and input in chart

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I would like to create a macro that run through a series of data in a table and is able to automatically graph it. The thing is, the data could have more or less points, but the code still needs to be able to select and graph this required data.

Here is what I'm working with (below). I would like to be able to graph the vertical coordinate vs. the vertical displacement for each of the point numbers (under column Point No.) on the same graph. As you can see there are four different point numbers (1,2,3,4)  and each point number is iterated 9 times. However, these numbers can change (for example there could be 8 Point numbers with three iterations each) and the code just needs to be able to select the data based on the point number value itself.

[image]
Here is an example of the graph that I wish to produce with this code:

[image: Example chart]

Since I'm very new to VBA, I still don't have a full grasp for the syntax but here was my thinking (**some NOT in VBA language**):

```
    Sub CreateChart()
Dim x as Range
    Range("C8").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'selects whole column which will always start from cell C8  

For each x in selection 

'Select the columns of *Vertical Coordinate* and *Vertical Displacement* corresponding to Point No. 1
'Graph the relationship as a new series in a scatterplot 

x = x+1

Next x

End Sub
```

I understand that this is completely incorrect syntax but again I only have very limited command of the language at this point. Any help is appreciated! Thx.

------------------------------!!!!!!!!!!!! **EDIT** !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-----------------------

I have received a great response from @Viktor for the scenario in the original case, but I was wondering if there was any way to modify the code for a slightly more challenging one (and one which is way above my head):

I have added a few more columns to my table (see below) and would like the code to create an additional chart that plots *Vertical Coordinate vs. Vertical Stress", while still keeping the chart from *Vertical Coordinate vs. Vertical Displacement*. The reason why the current code doesn't satisfy this is because it assumes that there is no other data on the sheet where the table is (but there is). I want to be able to add more columns and create more charts (all of them plotted against vertical coordinate) without affecting the other charts. Please if there is any way to modify the code then that would be much appreciated! Thx.

[image: Updated Data].com/GYsZo.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think the task is easier to complete using Formula + Named Ranges, but it was a challenge an a learning possibility to write the code. I hope it will work well for you.
I also tried to comment it for better understanding.

```
Sub MakeXYGraph()
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62285791/dynamically-select-cells-and-input-in-chart
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1 'This is the codename of the sheet where the data is
    'For the test, deleting all the previous charts
    Dim vChartObject As ChartObject
    For Each vChartObject In ws.ChartObjects
        vChartObject.Delete
    Next vChartObject
    'rngData is the range where the data are. It is assumed that nothing else is on the sheet than what you displ
    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
    ' Get the number of series
    Dim iMaxSeries As Integer
    iMaxSeries = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rngData.Columns(1))
    ' Is the actual Series, but in the sheet it called Point
    Dim iPoint As Integer
    'Used for setting the ranges for the series data
    Dim lFirstRow As Long, lLastRow As Long, lFirstColumn As Long, lLastColumn As Long
    lFirstColumn = rngData(1).Column
    lLastColumn = rngData.Columns(rngData.Columns.Count).Column
    'Creating the Chart
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=250, Width:=500, Top:=50, Height:=300)
    With cht.Chart
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
        'X axis name
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Vertical Displacement"
        'Y-axis name
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Vertical Coordinate"
        ' deleting the unwanted series (Excel tries to find out the data, but no need for it.)
        Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop
    End With
    For iPoint = 1 To iMaxSeries
        'Search for the first occurence of the point
        lFirstRow = rngData.Columns(1).Offset(-1).Find(what:=iPoint).Row
        'Search for the first occurence of the second point -1 is the last of this point
        If iPoint = iMaxSeries Then
            lLastRow = rngData.Rows(rngData.Rows.Count).Row - 1
        Else
            lLastRow = rngData.Columns(1).Find(what:=iPoint + 1).Row - 1
        End If
        'Add the series
        With cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = ws.Range(Cells(lFirstRow, lFirstColumn + 1), Cells(lLastRow, lLastColumn - 1))
            .Values = ws.Range(Cells(lFirstRow, lFirstColumn + 2), Cells(lLastRow, lLastColumn))
            .Name = "Point " & CStr(iPoint)
        End With
    Next iPoint
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Viktor! Thank you very much for your help with this. I just have a few questions: First, since my VBA is set for *Option Explicit*, it says that the variable "i" in the line `lFirstRow = rngData.Columns(1).Offset(-1).Find(what:=i).Row` is not defined. How can I fix this? Second, if in the future I would like to add more columns beside the Vertical Displacement column and graph it against the Vertical Coordinate column in the same way as before (essentially to make more graphs), how can I approach this? Thank you so much once again!

Comment: I am sorry. I made a silly mistake at the and to make the code more readable. I have corrected the code above. Hopefully good :)  (The problem was that I have forgot the rename all the i to iPoint.)

Comment: Addressing the second part of your comment: I am not sure how do you mean. You may increase the number of the "points" to any number. Those will be shown in the graph as new series.

Comment: Hi @Vikor! That seemed to clear up that problem, however now when I run the code I get a *Excel VBA run-time error 1004 : Application-defined or object-defined error* pop-up, and when I click *Debug* it tells me the problem is for the line of code `Set rngData = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)`. Do you know what the problem could be? Thank you! :)

Comment: You should have your data in the "sheet1" but nothing else. (I am using the UsedRange).

Comment: @Vickor yes Thank you it does work when there is nothing else on the sheet except for that data that I specified in the original question. That's good! However, eventually I plan on adding more and different data onto that worksheet. Is there any way to modify the code so that it will do the same thing  as it currently does even if there is more data on the sheet? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you not changing the structure (3 column) you can select the range by modifying the Set rngData  = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1). The easiest is Set rngData = ws.range("B2:D44"). Of course it is not flexible. There are so many possibilities to choose.

Comment: Hi @Viktor, I have updated the original question above if that helps you to understand my question. Thank you for all of your help.